# Spark streaming with kafka avro serialization

Tags: java, apache-kafka, cassandra, spark-streaming, spark-cassandra-connector

I am storing data into Kafka using schema registry and avro serialization. Now I have to consume this messages from Kafka and store it in 2 places. One is parquet file and other one is Cassandra database. After lot of search I found that to perform above two tasks we need to convert streaming rdd's to data frame. However I am not able get java implementation for the same.
Can you please suggest on this.

Sample code:

```
JavaPairReceiverInputDstream<String, GenericRecord> = KafkaUtils.createStream(jssc, String.class,
    GenericRecord.class, KafkavroDecoder.class,
    KafkavroDecoder.class, Kafkaesque,topicMap);

JavaDStream<GenericRecord> msg= Kafka.map(
new Function<Tuple2<String, GenericRecord>, GenericRecord>(){
public GenericRecord call(Tuple2<String, GenericRecord> Tuple2) {
      return tuple2._2();
   }
});

msg.print(); // output looks like :: Id=1 name= man
```

I want store above data in Cassandra table.

Comment: just call `.toDF` on RDD? You can save to Cassandra from RDD as well

Comment: Thanks for the response. It would be great help if you can provide any example code for reference.

Comment: Please show your code that doesn't work

Comment: And also versions of Spark, Spark-Cassandra connector, etc.

Comment: I am using Spark version 2.1.0 and spark-cassandra-connector_2.10-1.6.0.jar

Comment: I have added code snippet which I am using

Comment: Did you try to use connector 2.0.7?

Comment: I don't see any attempts to convert into DataFrame... Source code is incomplete - please refer Cassandra Spark connector documentation for examples on how to use with Spark Streaming